# Android: don't show soft keyboard in AutocompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-softkeyboard, autocompletetextview

I have an `AutocompleteTextView` to select a train station, which is using **two different adapters**:

**ADAPTER 1**: containing a fixed list of recent and nearby stations (**DOESN'T require a soft keyboard** for filtering by typing)
**ADAPTER 2**: containing the cursor to the sqlite database of stations (**DOES require a soft keyboard** for filtering by typing)

So, I would like to prevent the soft keyboard from showing when the AutocompleteTextView gets the focus and the ADAPTER 1 is used, but I haven't found a way yet.

I am currently using this, but the soft keyboard keeps popping up:
`InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);`

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way!
On the onFocusChange you first set the focus to its parent and after that you call `showDropDown()` to display the dropdown. In this way the keyboard doesn't pop up, because the `AutocompleteTextView` doesn't have the focus!

```
    setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {
                setAdapter(Adapter1);
                ((ViewGroup)getParent()).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                ((ViewGroup)getParent()).requestFocus();
                showDropDown();
            }
        }
    });
```